# How do I generate a list of coordinates (lat, long) from list of coordinates generated using numpy arange

Tags: python, coordinates

I am trying to generate a txt file that has lat, long, i, j, z values. I have been able to create a list of i,j, z values using the following:

```
n = 51
m = 31

data = [(i,j,i*2) for i in range(n) for j in range(m)]
```

However, I am not sure how to do this if I create a range of values using numpy arange

```
lat = np.arange(33.8916,34.0426,0.003)
long = np.arange(78.0136,77.9236,-0.003)
```

Is there a way to do this? Both (n, m) and (lat, long) are the same dimensions, (51,31). So what I would like to have is a txt file that has:

```
33.8916,78.0136,0,0,0
33.8946,78.0166,0,1,0
...
34.0416,77.9236,50,30,100
```

Comment: The lat/log coordinates in your expected output do not look like the list `data`.

Comment: `len(data)` = 1581, whereas `len(lat)` = 51. Do you want to repeat `lat` and `long` 31 times?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I know they don't but that is what I am trying to get answered, how do I get them to be in the same format so then I can export them to a txt file such as in the bottom of my question. Let me know if that does not make sense and I can try to clarify if you think you're able to give a solution.

Comment: @Chris I believe I want 1581 lines, so yes to repeating 31 times? What I want is for my text file output to have 1581 lines. What I am trying to do is make a grid with lat, long, i, j, z(depth) values. So each point in the grid has a line in the text file.

Comment: @fallfish see if the answer posted helps?

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip()`:

```
n = 51
m = 31

data = [(i,j,i*2) for i in range(n) for j in range(m)]
data = [', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in data]   # removing the tuples

lat = np.arange(33.8916,34.0426,0.003)
long = np.arange(78.0136,78.1036,0.003)

res = list(zip(lat,long,data))     # zipping the lists together

logFile = "list.txt"

with open(logFile, "w") as f:
   for data in res:
       f.write("%s, %s, %s" % data + "\n")
```

**OUTPUT (list.txt)**:

```
33.8916, 78.0136, 0, 0, 0
33.8946, 78.0166, 0, 1, 0
33.8976, 78.0196, 0, 2, 0
33.9006, 78.0226, 0, 3, 0
33.9036, 78.0256, 0, 4, 0
33.9066, 78.0286, 0, 5, 0
.
.
.
```

**EDIT**:

To get all the way till the `data`, use `zip_longest()`:

```
res = list(zip_longest(lat,long,data))

logFile = "list.txt"

with open(logFile, "w") as f:
    for data in res:
        f.write("%s, %s, %s" % data + "\n")
```

> Note: Using `zip_longest` inserts `None` at the `missing` values

**For example**:

```
print(len(data))    # 1581
print(len(lat))     # 51
print(len(long))    # 31
```

Hence:

**OUTPUT**:

```
33.8916, 78.0136, 0, 0, 0
33.8946, 78.0166, 0, 1, 0
33.8976, 78.0196, 0, 2, 0
.
.
33.9846, None, 1, 0, 2
33.9876, None, 1, 1, 2
.
.
None, None, 50, 28, 100
None, None, 50, 29, 100
None, None, 50, 30, 100
```

**EDIT 2**:

To have consistent lists, make the following changes:

```
n = 2
m = 23

lat = np.arange(33.8916,34.0426,0.0033)
long = np.arange(78.0136,78.1036,0.002)
```

Comment: So it looks like it could work, but this only goes to lat, long, 0, 30, 0. I want every combination. so I would like it to go up to (34.0416,78.1036,50,30,100). So how I am able to do n=51 and m=31 to get coordinates 0,0 to 50,30 I also want to do the same with the lat long, if that makes sense?

Comment: thank you so much for your help!  Why would there be missing values?

Comment: I was just thanking you for your effort, but I still don't have a solution :/ I am trying to get the lat, long to be the same length as data so there should not be any missing values in my output. I will keep looking, thanks!

Comment: @fallfish your question did not have that in particular, You need to change the size of `lat` long` or perhaps the `data` to have them of same size. How do you want to do? Since I do not know the intention behind the manipulation of that.

Comment: I had my lat and long values listed incorrectly. There should be the same number of values for n,m as there are for lat, long. I have fixed it in my post. Not sure if that clarifies things? What I want is to create a grid with both i,j and lat, long values. So for each i,j there should be an equivalent lat, long for that point in the grid.

Comment: @fallfish Indeed, that is what I tried explaining in the first edit as well.

Comment: yea, I got it. used location = [(x,y) for x in np.arange(33.8916,34.0426,0.003) for y in np.arange(78.0136,77.9236,-0.003)]

Comment: @fallfish great. If the answer helped you may accept it :) cheers